# When is it acceptable to use roughness without a map input in the Principled BDSF node?

Tags: materials

For a PBR material setup, one usually have map inputs for the color, roughness, normal nodes. If a material has an undefined roughness, but it's not perfectly smooth either, is it okay to use the roughness slider as a substitute for a map input? Would such a technique have an impact on the photo realism of the object?

Comment: The title has a mistake in it - there is no such thing as 'roughness node'. You are talking about roughness input. It shouuld be something like 'When is it acceptable to use the roughness input without a map for it in Principled BDSF node?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to use a single value for roughness in all the cases when roughness is uniform across the surface for example with smooth clean objects made of the same material.